# How to add custom item in woocommerce order editor

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets, hook-woocommerce

Good day to all of you,

I just want to ask if it is possible to add custom item at the woocommerce backend, we want to input names and etc, its just like the Add fee button but the problem is Add fee button ask like this after we click it "Enter a fixed amount or percentage to apply as a fee." and we will input zero then click edit and change the label to what we want, now is there any snippets code or a plugin that can add another button "Add particular" after the Add product(s) and ask only for a name or anything. Please check my screenshot.

Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVF36.png

Comment: can anyone please help me with this issue...thank you.

Comment: Mostly everything is doable… But what you ask without providing any code is just something really advanced, a real development. So it's something too broad for StackOverflow.